# C# - Update GUI datagridview from another thread using delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, delegates

I'm trying to update a datagridview with some data calculated in a different class and thread, using a delegate. Unfortunately I'm having trouble with a variety of different errors, depending on the approach I try.

The code I am trying to execute in the form thread looks like this:

```
public partial class AcquireForm : Form
//
// ...
//
    // update the grid with results
    public delegate void delUpdateResultsGrid(int Index, Dictionary<string, double> scoreCard);
    public void UpdateResultsGrid(int Index, Dictionary<string, double> scoreCard)
    {
        if (!this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //
            // Some code to sort the data from scoreCard goes here
            //

            DataGridViewRow myRow = dataGridViewResults.Rows[Index];
            DataGridViewCell myCell = myRow.Cells[1];
            myCell.Value = 1; // placeholder - the updated value goes here
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new delUpdateResultsGrid(UpdateResultsGrid), new object[] { Index, scoreCard});
        }
    }
```

Now, I need to get this method to run from my other thread and class. I have tried:

```
public class myOtherClass
//
// ...
//

    private void myOtherClassMethod(int myIndex)
    {
        // ...
        AcquireForm.delUpdateResultsGrid updatedelegate = new AcquireForm.delUpdateResultsGrid(AcquireForm.UpdateResultsGrid);
        updatedelegate(myIndex, myScoreCard);
    }
```

Unfortunately this gives an "Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property AcquireForm.UpdateResultsGrid(int, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary)" error. I seem to be unable to reference the UpdateResultsGrid method at all...

I have noticed that

```
public class myOtherClass
//
// ...
//

    private void myOtherClassMethod(int myIndex)
    {
        // ...
        AcquireForm acquireForm = new AcquireForm();
        acquireForm.UpdateResultsGrid(myIndex,myScoreCard);
    }
```

does not throw any errors when compiling, but it tries to create a new form and that is something I do not want to do. I don't want to create a new instance of AcquireForm, I want to reference the pre-existing one, if that's possible.

I have also tried making the UpdateResultsGrid method static, but this throws up problems with several things incuding the use of "this.(anything)".

I've also tried moving the majority of the UpdateResultsGrid method into myOtherClassMethod, leaving behind in the AcquireForm class just the delegate. Again, this does not work because many of the references to UI objects break (there aren't any dataGridViews in scope).

I'm starting to run out of ideas here. Unfortunately I'm rather new to C# (as you can probably tell), and I'm editing someone else's code rather than writing my own entirely from scratch. If anyone could offer some advice on this problem it'd be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your *objects* are communicating with each other: Your `myOtherClass` is going to have to know about the AcquireForm object - you can't just create a new one (as you've discovered). You'll need to pass the AcquireForm **object** into the myOtherClass **object** (myOtherObject.SetForm(myAcquireForm, for example) and reference it when you need to.

In case you're having issues with invoking this might be of help - how I invoke a "next" button click:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>button_next_Click(null,null)));
```

Moreover, it sounds like maybe this should not be separate classes and you should be utilising a [BackgroundWorkder](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx&ei=1rBFUuyVK8ix0QWMqYAI&usg=AFQjCNFwLYOqQ7vrjVJ7SroICXQH-GDyEQ&sig2=W4ie-Sw5GjwTM1fJ9rSCnw&bvm=bv.53217764,d.d2k) instead.

Comment: Hi noelicus, many thanks for taking the time to help me with this. Would you be able to elaborate slightly? I tried adding a line:

[code]myOtherClass.SetForm(AcquireForm);[/code]

but that didn't work - SetForm doesn't seem to be recognised as a valid definition. I agree that I need to get the myOtherClass to recognise the AcquireForm object, but could you provide some more advice as to how to do that?

Comment: You need to make sure you're *objects* are communicating - what you have typed implies you might do well to read up on the difference between a class and an object is. Also, I'd recommend trying to make what you've got one class from what you've said - then these problems go away.

Comment: Okay, I think I've cracked it. I added a field to the constructor for myOtherClass of type AcquireForm, then used "this" when creating an instance of the class from the AcquireForm. That seems to work without errors for now, but I'll look into merging the classes when I have a bit more time on it.

Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: To obtain a reference to the required form from your separate class, you could loop through the Application.OpenForms collection. You would need to be able to identify your form in the list, but this is easily achieved.